# What datatype should I use for my Tickets table?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I'm creating a table which is set to list out the prices of tickets for specific venues of a tour in my database.

The price needs to be in UK currency (£0.00) as the tours are based in the UK. However when it comes to setting the datatypes for the price columns I was unsure what datatype would allow the format of UK currency to fit. So I used DOUBLE PRECISION but when trying to input these values:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_Tickets` (`Student_Price`, `Adult_Price`, `OAP_Price`, `Tourdate_id`)
VALUES ('£15.00', '£22.00' ,'£13.50', 1);
```

I get a 0, each of the price columns.

What datatype should I set my price columns to, to allow UK currency to properly fit?

Comment: If you need to store the currency symbol, then a numeric type won't work. You'd have to go with character string. But I don't recommend you do that. A better pattern would be to store the currency/units in a separate column,  and store the numeric value in a DECIMAL(m,n).  If you were using SQL Server and chose to use a MONEY datatype, SQL Server would accept the currency symbol in the assignment, but it discards it and never stores it. If you need it stored, you would need to store the currency symbol or code separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a [fixed-point numeric](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) type to store currency of any nationality, eg. `DECIMAL(5, 2)` which would store values up to 999.99.

As spencer7593 points out below, there's no need to be stingy with the number of digits, as the [`DECIMAL` type's storage format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) is quite compact.

Comment: Don't be stingy with the number of digits. `DECIMAL(6,2)` uses no more bytes than `DECIMAL(5,2)`. (We get two digits per byte; 2 bytes for the 4 digits before the decimal point, 1 byte for the two digits after. If we want to use another byte, we can jump to `DECIMAL(8,2)`. And we go for four bytes before the decimal point, we get one extra digit for free! `DECIMAL(11,2)`.

Comment: I used the DECIMAL (5, 2) datatype instead, but again all I'm getting is 0.00. I need to include the £ symbol with the value and I think that's what's stopping the field from accepting the data.

Comment: If all the values are in pounds, you don't need to (and shouldn't) store the currency symbol. Just add it in the reports.

Comment: If all the values aren't in pounds, then you should store the currency in a separate column (since most systems dealing in multiple currencies will want to use exchange rates and do maths with the numbers … for that matter even if you only have a single currency you'll still want to do maths (e.g. if people buy multiple tickets).

Comment: You _must_ cleanse your data entry _before_ storing.  That means getting rid of the currency symbol, thousands-separators, leading/trailing spaces, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You must never, never, never use a floating-point datatype for money. You *must always* use a decimal radix, in this case DECIMAL(*N,* 2), where *N* is some reasonably high upper bound on values, their sums, etc, such as ten, or much more if you're running a bank. The 2 is because you have 100 pence to the pound, but again there are cases where you might want a bit more.